# fsl resampled image comes out cropped

Tags: image-processing, medical-imaging, nifti

I am using fsleyes to resample image by providing reference image, but the generated resampled image is cropped ?

[image: please see here]
the blue is resampled overlay

I tried increasing the resolution of reference image but that doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

I translated the image over referenced image before applying resampling it seemed to work.